# Incorrect output from batch script execution

Tags: windows, batch-file

i am trying to run below snippet of code on my windows server.

```
@echo off
set BRANCH_NAME_ID=compiler_branch
if %BRANCH_NAME_ID%==compiler_branch ( echo INSIDE COMPILER BRANCH )
echo %BRANCH_SHORT_ID%|findstr /r "^[r][0-9][0-9]*_00$" & IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (  echo IN IF ) ELSE ( echo INFO else)
pause
```

I was expecting the only output should be `INSIDE COMPILER BRANCH` because, `BRANCH_NAME_ID` variable is referring to `compiler_branch`. But some reason i am also getting `IN IF` as well.

Ouptut:-

```
INSIDE COMPILER BRANCH
IN IF
Press any key to continue . . .
```

As per the document https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html i notice below and wrote the script accordingly. But some reason `%ERRORLEVEL%` is setting to `0` in line3 of my code thought the string is not matching :-

```
FINDSTR will set %ERRORLEVEL% as follows:

0 A match is found in at least one line of at least one file.
1 If a match is not found in any line of any file, (or if the file is not found at all).
2 Wrong syntax
```

An invalid switch will only print an error message in error stream.

Am i missing something ?

Comment: Replace `IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0` with `if not errorlevel 1`. Batch parses the entire logical line, substitutes the **current** values for any `%varname%`, then executes the command, so it is substituting the value of `errorlevel` at the time that the `echo` is parsed. The syntax given will act on the run-time value.

Answer (score 0):

Because of how the interpreter reads files (see [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts) for a massive amount of info), `%ERRORLEVEL%` in that line gets replaced with its current value before the line is actually run. In order to have the command run and then have the value checked correctly, put the `if` statement on its own line.

```
@echo off
set BRANCH_NAME_ID=compiler_branch
if %BRANCH_NAME_ID%==compiler_branch ( echo INSIDE COMPILER BRANCH )
echo %BRANCH_SHORT_ID%|findstr /r "^[r][0-9][0-9]*_00$"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (  echo IN IF ) ELSE ( echo INFO else)
pause
```

If for some reason you absolutely insist on using `&` to chain commands together (there is no reason to ever do this and it only makes things worse imo), then you can enable delayed expansion and use `!ERRORLEVEL!` instead.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set BRANCH_NAME_ID=compiler_branch
if %BRANCH_NAME_ID%==compiler_branch ( echo INSIDE COMPILER BRANCH )
echo %BRANCH_SHORT_ID%|findstr /r "^[r][0-9][0-9]*_00$" & IF !ERRORLEVEL! == 0 (  echo IN IF ) ELSE ( echo INFO else)
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually here there is an issue where this particular line `echo %BRANCH_SHORT_ID%|findstr /r "^[r][0-9][0-9]*_00$"` causes issue which returns `exited non-zero errorlevel=1` . Script is able to proceed further lines after above line.. And my overall script exit status will become non-zero. Seems like `findstr` tries to look for the pattern and if it doesn't match exit status is returning as non zero. Any WAR to resolve this ?

Comment: `%ERRORLEVEL%` stays the same until something else changes it, so if the last thing to set it was the `findstr` command, that's what it will return. If you want to reset the errorlevel to 0 for some reason, you can run any command that resets it. I usually use `ver >nul`.

Comment: ERRORLEVEL is fine. But with `findstr` usage, that doesn't match the pattern causes exit status to non-zero.  So you mean that WAR for that is to reset the errorlevel as 0 ? could you please elaborate on `ver >nul`? In my case what would be the solution ?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "WAR"?

Comment: And `findstr` sets errorlevel to 0 when it finds a match and 1 when it doesn't, like you said in your question already. Exit status _IS_ errorlevel.

Comment: I mean WAR in the sense Work around:)

Comment: Workaround is one word so you can't abbreviate it ;)